# Splitting Mulitpolygon into separate polygons for entry to SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: sql-server-2012, spatial-query, mapinfo

I'm trying to spatialise a table of 400 polygons (MapInfo tab layer) all of which are adjacent to each other into a `SQL Server 2012` database. There are no polygons within polygons etc.

I want one row per polygon but I can only generate one row for all 400. I have the `WKT` and a sample of the code I'm using is:

```
select geometry::STGeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON( ((319621.99946835 
110837.002493295,   319640.501385461 110850.59860145,   319695.199120806 
110879.700271183,   319728.303041127 110879.300385649,  319752.898058391 
110876.501186912,   319767.401120868 110872.702274339,  319786.199860179 
110873.60201679,    319789.102121686 110887.897924629,  319792.103323927 
110898.504888418,   319794.29651018 110916.299794679,   319812.699486557 
110940.202952471,   319621.99946835 110837.002493295)),  
((319910.700282805 110880.699985018,    319916.900568753 
110861.595453633,   319941.602771812 110838.00220713,   319973.601853945 
110866.004191645,   320000.002539591 110899.404630869,  320025.999217243 
110931.295502202,   320034.301993772 110944.001865043,  320038.696611339 
110948.600548684,   319910.700282805 110880.699985018)))', 4326)
```

I hope I don't have to do this 400 times!

```
select geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((319621.99946835 
110837.002493295,   319640.501385461 110850.59860145,   319695.199120806 
110879.700271183,   319728.303041127 110879.300385649,  319752.898058391 
110876.501186912,   319767.401120868 110872.702274339,  319786.199860179 
110873.60201679,    319789.102121686 110887.897924629,  319792.103323927 
110898.504888418,   319794.29651018 110916.299794679,   319812.699486557 
110940.202952471,   319621.99946835 110837.002493295))', 4326) 

select geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((319910.700282805 
110880.699985018,   319916.900568753 110861.595453633,  319941.602771812 
110838.00220713,    319973.601853945 110866.004191645,  320000.002539591 
110899.404630869,   320025.999217243 110931.295502202,  320034.301993772 
110944.001865043,   320038.696611339 110948.600548684,  319910.700282805 
110880.699985018))', 4326)
```

Currently the data is in a `SQL Server 2005` database but we are migrating to `SQL Server 2012` soon.

In the future, the business will make changes to only certain sections of the layer and then I would hope to just spatialise those changes.

As spatial functions are not native to `SQL Server 2005` stack, I have `SpatialWare` from `MapInfo` that did this for me via it's `EasyLoader` utility but in `SQL Server 2012`, because the spatial functions are now native, `MapInfo` is only spatialising the centroids of the polygons. Otherwise this would be the easiest and preferred option.

If anyone could tell me how I can use `MapInfo` to spatialise the table so I get all 400 rows or alternativley, the correct `SQL`, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Have solved this by upgrading to a later version of MapInfo which supports spatialising for SQL Server. Would still appreciate if any one could shed some insight into doing this via SQL. Thanks.